# Get the list of services for a subscription instead of resources

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to list all the services used within a subscription, programmatically with Python.

How to do so since I do not want to end up with a list of resources ? (e.g a VM creates several resources, but I would like to know only about the VM service, not all the stuff around)

EDIT : From a "more business oriented point of view" I would like to be able to know how many PaaS resources (and which ones) a subscription is using, same for IaaS. But for instance I do not care about network interfaces coming with VMs on creation.
I'd like to end up with something like : 2 VMs, 3 SQL Dbs, 1 App Service, 2 App Insights, etc.

I can't find anything else than `ResourceManagementClient` that (obviously) does not return the precise data I'd like. ServiceManagementClient-alike would be perfect, is there any trick ? It would be a pain to code everything by hand for excluding unnecessary stuff.

Comment: What do you mean by "service"?

Comment: I updated my question, it was unclear !

Comment: Sounds like all you need to do is filter out which ResourceTypes you need to count